# How to get selected image map alt value?

Tags: javascript, html

ok changed my code:

```
      <div class="a" id="mySidenav">
         <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">X</a>
         <a href="#" id="tname">Number:</a>
         <a href="#" id="d1"></a>
         <a href="#" id="d2"></a>
      </div>
      <map class="b" name="mymap" id="map">
         <area shape="circle" coords="67,420,20" onclick="openNav(this)" alt="5" />
         <area shape="circle" coords="184,384,19" onclick="openNav(this)" alt="6" />
      </map>
     function openNav(element){
     $('#mySidenav').css("width", "250px");
     $('#image').css("marginLeft", "250px");
     var alt = $(element).attr("alt");
       $('#tname').text(alt);
     }
```

i have folders named "5" and "6" and so on. each folders have `1.html 2.html` that has `<title>PersonName</title>` if i clicked image map with alt=5 i want to get '5/1.html' `<title>` value appear on `"id=d1"` and it should become link to that html.  tried this one, but not working, seems like im making syntax error

```
$.get('1.html'), openNav(result){
    var obj = $(result).find('title');
    $(this).append($('#d1').text(obj.html()));
```

Comment: I extended my response below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the attribute with plain JavaScript with `.getAttribute("alt")` or with jQuery with `.attr("alt")`. However, you need to select the correct element first. You can do this e.g. with jQuery with `$("#map area")`. It is however easier to pass the element directly by in the function.

HTML:

```
<map class="b" name="mymap" id="map">
   <area shape="circle" coords="67,420,20" onclick="openNav(this)" alt="5" />
   <area shape="circle" coords="184,384,19" onclick="openNav(this)" alt="6" />
</map>
```

JavaScript:

```
function openNav(element) {
   var alt = element.getAttribute("alt");
   document.getElementById("tname").innerHTML = alt;
}

// or with jQuery
function openNav(element) {
   var alt = $(element).attr("alt");
   $("#tname").text(alt);
}
```

---

*The answer for the question after your edit:*

The proper solution would be to set a click listener on the area. Inside of this clicklistener, you create the whole logic, like this.

First, remove every `onclick=""` from your HTML document.

Then, use this JavaScript snippet:

```
$("#map area").click(function() {
    var alt = $(this).attr("alt");
    var address1 = alt + "/1.html";
    var address2 = alt + "/2.html";

    $.get({
        url: address1,
        success: function(result) {
            var title = $.parseHTML(result).find("title").text();
            $("#d1").text(title).attr("href", address1);
        }
    });
    $.get({
        url: address2,
        success: function(result) {
            var title = $.parseHTML(result).find("title").text();
            $("#d2").text(title).attr("href", address2);
        }
    });
});
```

There is of course room for improvements (e.g. DRY concept etc.).

Comment: If the question is unrelated to this one, you should create a new one, if it is just an addition to this one, you can edit your question accordingly.